# Accessing Spring applicationContext, or any bean, from an external library

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber-java

I am trying to move common Cucumber step definitions from our spring applications into its own library. This way I can reuse the same functions across multiple services.

However, to run some of the step definitions I need access to Application context and MockMvc. 
Is there a way to autowire the a bean from any spring application into my library?

I've tried the following in library

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = StepDefinitonConfig.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class StepDefinitonConfig {

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;
}

mockMvc.perform(post(url/here)...
MockWebServiceClient mockWs = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);
```

And this in the spring application

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/bdd",
        glue = {"com.my.library.etc"})
```

I assume I'm missing a key principle of how the spring scans the classpath, but cant see it!

Comment: What do you mean by "this in the spring application"? Is it how the Test fixture used to be?
Please update your post with a minimal test fixture implementation and provide the output: it just does not work or are you getting an exception thrown?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying be concise in my question so have skimped on the detail. Spring application is my micro service. yes I use to have my Test fixed to the micro service, but with the increase in micro services, I have seen I am repeating the step definitions. Also I was getting the no available bean, null pointer, which is now resolved since following the below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [`cucumber-spring`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/spring) you can autowire any bean, including the application context into your step definitions. It does not matter where you step definitions are, as long as they are on the glue path.

```java
package com.example.lib;

public class MyStepDefinitions {

   @Autowired
   private MyService myService;

   @Given("feed back is requested from my service")
   public void feed_back_is_requested(){
      myService.requestFeedBack();
   }
}
```

So if some of your step definitions are in the `com.example.lib` package and some in the `com.example.app` package you'd include both by using:

```
package com.example;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(glue = {"com.example.app", "com.example.lib"})
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

Note: You'll also need to tell Cucumber which class should be used to boot strap your application context. This class should also be on your glue path. For example:

```
import com.example.app;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import io.cucumber.spring.CucumberContextConfiguration;

@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class CucumberSpringConfiguration {

}
```

Comment: OK. That has massively helped and I am now able to access application context etc.
When you say I need to tell Cucumber which class to use, do you mean by setting the SpringBootTest to scan Step definitions? 
Also, I now have the issue where I am unable to access the Controllers, so I assume my @SpringBootTest is not scanning the spring boot app config @SpringBootApplication?

Comment: `cucumber-spring` is using springs `TestContextManager` under the hood. Cucumber will pass the class annotated with `@CucumberContextConfiguration` to the test context manager.

I believe `@SpringBootTest`  requires the `@SpringBootApplication`  annotated class to be in the same package or it will fail to detect it.